# Removing rows in data frame using get function

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have following data frame:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA),score=11:16)
```

I want to get following data frame at the end:

```
mydataframe[-which(is.na(mydataframe$ID)),]
```

I need to do this kind of cleaning (and other similar manipulations) with many other data frames. So, I decided to assign a name to mydataframe, and variable of interest.

```
dbname <- "mydataframe"
varname <- "ID"
attach(get(dbname))
```

I get an error in the following line, understandably.

```
get(dbname) <- get(dbname)[-which(is.na(get(varname))),]
detach(get(dbname))
```

How can I solve this? (I don't want to assign to a new data frame, even though it seems only solution right now. I will use "dbname" many times afterwards.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Egads.  Why?  Why are you doing this?  I guarantee there is a better way.  Most likely using lists.  It always comes down to using lists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `get<-` function, and there is no `get(colname)` function (since colnames are not first class objects), but there is an `assign()` function:

```
assign(dbname,  get(dbname)[!is.na( get(dbname)[varname] ), ] )
```

You also do not want to use `-which(.)`. It would have worked here since there were some matches to the condition. It will bite you, however, whenever there are not any rows that match and instead of returning nothing as it should, it will return everything, since `vec[numeric(0)] == vec`. Only use `which` for "positive" choices.

Comment: I like your explanation concerning `which`. Anyway, is there any difference between your code and `mydataframe[!is.na(mydataframe[varname]),]`, i.e. are there any advantages when using `assign`?

Comment: I doubt very much that there would be much difference between `mydataframe <- mydataframe[!is.na(mydataframe[varname]),]` and the `assign` version. I offered the `assign` version was to show how to get the assignment done with a character value for the "name" which appeared to be your strategy. The `assign` function's role is to convert its first argument, given as a character value, to an R language-name and complete the assignment.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. Learning "get(dbname)[varname]", also very helpful to me. Also, thanks for showing the possible loophole in "-which(.)".

Answer (score 4):

As @Dason suggests, lists are made for this sort of work.

E.g.:

```
# make a list with all your data.frames in it 
# (just repeating the one data.frame 3x for this example)
alldfs <- list(mydataframe,mydataframe,mydataframe)

# apply your function to all the data.frames in the list
# have replaced original function in line with @DWin and @flodel's comments
# pointing out issues with using -which(...)
lapply(alldfs, function(x) x[!is.na(x$ID),])
```

Comment: +1 but please read @DWin's comment about not using `-which` and fix your code. Another elegant way here is to do `lapply(alldfs, subset, !is.na(ID))`.

Comment: @flodel - good point, I didn't even assess the function being used when I slapped it into the `lapply`. Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion to use a list of data frames is good, but I think people are assuming that you're in a situation where all the data frames are loaded simultaneously. This might not necessarily be the case, eg if you're working on a number of projects and just want some boilerplate code to use in all of them.

Something like this should fit the bill.

```
stripNAs <- function(df, var) df[!is.na(df[[var]]), ]

mydataframe <- stripNAs(mydataframe, "ID")
cars <- stripNAs(cars, "speed")
```

Comment: When I tried this it gives me following error: Error in df[[var]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Should be `mydataframe <- stripNAs(mydataframe, "ID")`

Answer (score 1):

I can totally understand your need for this, since I also frequently need to cycle through a set of data frames. I believe the following code should help you out:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA),score=11:16)

#define target dataframe and varname
dbname <- "mydataframe"
varname <- "ID"

tmp.df <- get(dbname) #get df and give it a temporary name
col.focus <- which(colnames(tmp.df) == varname) #define the column of focus
tmp.df <- tmp.df[which(!is.na(tmp.df[,col.focus])),] #cut out the subset of the df where the column of focus is not NA. 

#Result
  ID score
1  1    11
2  2    12
4  4    14
5  5    15
```